# Google App Engine JasperReports

Tags: web-services, google-app-engine, jasper-reports

So I have created a local java web application and many JasperReports. It is now time to move to production and I think I am going to use the Google App Engine. Before I started though I wanted to make sure all my JasperReports would work?

The previous questions regarding this were from 3-5 years ago, so I was just wondering if the Google App Engine now supports this?

Or should I use Amazon Elastic Beanstalk? (If this even supports JasperReports also)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't work on App Engine. Jasper Reports uses classes from AWT/Swing, that are restricted on App Engine

Btw, as you're comparing App Engine to Beanstalk (that's different things anyway), then maybe [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) or [Container Engine](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/) could help you? There're no any restrictions, just plain VMs, you may run anything here. And Google Cloud will provide load balancing, automatic scaling and restart after failure.

PS Also, I don't think that "just app" can be moved to App Engine. App Engine is very specific platform, and app should be designed specifically for App Engine from the beginning.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I'll look into Google Compute Engine more and might use Bitnami with it as it seems simple and easy.

Comment: The new release of java 8 on Google App Engine may change this answer to yes.